# Alinhar divs, com ou sem Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, grid

Olá, preciso de uma grid centralizada usando bootstrap, consegui fazer isso usando `flex` e `justify-content-center`:

```css
   
.item {
  border: dashed 1px blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center container">
  <div class="item">Conteudo 01</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 02</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 03</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 04</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 05</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 06</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 07</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 08</div>
</div>
```

No entanto, repare que quando a linha é quebrada, as divs que vão para baixo ficam centralizadas também, há alguma forma de, após quebrar a linha, as divs que sobraram ficarem alinhadas á esquerda?
O resultado esperado seria assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Edit: Consegui fazer sem usar Bootstrap

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.containerGrid {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  width: min-content;
  
  /* Centralizando Container */
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
.item {
  text-align: center;
  border: dashed 1px blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerGrid">
    <div class="item">Conteudo 01</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 02</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 03</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 04</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 05</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 06</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 07</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 08</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 09</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Repare que, após a quebra de linha, os `items` div vão para o lado esquerdo do container, e todos os itens do container se mantêm centralizados.

Comment: Vc até consegue, mas vai acontecer isso https://prnt.sc/13qvf8p já que ele não centraliza, onde não couber um item inteiro ele vai quebrar a linha e deixar um espaço em branco, a melhor foma de tratar isso é com display:grid e não display:flex

Answer (score 0):

Diretamente no html não consigo pensar em nenhuma solução porém pelo css conseguimos fazer é só usar o nth-child.

```css
.div-principal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  &:nth-child(7) {
    justify-content: left;
  }

  &:nth-child(8) {
    justify-content: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito Bom essa resolução, no entanto, a quantidade de elementos são mudadas dinamicamente, então não posso usar uma posição especifica como chil(8) ou child(7).

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver faltou apenas o justify-content-start se for apenas com bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="containerGrid">
    <div class="item">Conteudo 01</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 02</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 03</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 04</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 05</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 06</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 07</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 08</div>
    <div class="item">Conteudo 09</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.item {
  border: dashed 1px blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start container">
  <div class="item">Conteudo 01</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 02</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 03</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 04</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 05</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 06</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 07</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 08</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 09</div>
  <div class="item">Conteudo 10</div>
</div>
```